# Fluent NHibernate — specify table/column names when using HiLo generator

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, hilo

Yes, nit-picky is a good way to describe this...  ;)

Does anyone know if you can specify the table and/or column names to use HiLo using Fluent NHibernate?  Currently the schema export creates this...

```
create table hibernate_unique_key (
     next_hi INTEGER 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
public class IdGenerationConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.GeneratedBy.HiLo("MyTableName", "NextHighValue", "1000");
    }
}
```